# Using db2 merge with php parameters

Tags: sql, merge, db2

I have a working insert going into DB2, using PHP parameters in a script. It works just as I want for an isnert but I'm trying to fix it up so that I don't have to truncate and rebuild every time. I'd like to simply update my last 2 fields if my unique key fields already exist.

The insert:

```
INSERT INTO testSchema.metrics (cust, item, material, color, group, group2, sales, score )
    VALUES (
        :cust_id, 
        :item,
        :material,
        :color,
        :group,
        :group2,
        :sales,
        :score
    )
```

I have a unique key constraint on cust_id, item, material and color so I'm trying to do an UPSERT basically, but in DB2.

I know I can use MERGE in DB2, and I've started to here, but I'm simply confused at how to flesh this out, especially since I'm using parameters from the script.

here's my psuedo merge:

```
MERGE INTO testSchema.metrics as m
USING // I guess I would need all of my parameters here?
ON :cust_id, :item, :material, :color
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET sales = :sales, score = :score
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (cust, item, material, color, group, group2, sales, score )
    VALUES (
            :cust_id, 
            :item,
            :material,
            :color,
            :group,
            :group2,
            :sales,
            :score
        );
```

I feel that's the basic idea but I'm confused how to fix up the USING and ON lines for the parameters.

I'm just trying to say (If a row matches on cust_id, item, material and color, then update with new sales and score. Else, insert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [IBM tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/merge?lang=en) (under "Single row MERGE using VALUES" section), you would only need to set parameters in one place in the `USING` clause and then map each to an alias, *S*. Then define the `MATCHED` and `NOT MATCHED` logic.

```
MERGE INTO testSchema.metrics AS T 
      USING (VALUES (
                     :cust_id, 
                     :item,
                     :material,
                     :color,
                     :group,
                     :group2,
                     :sales,
                     :score
                    )
             ) 
     AS S(CUST_ID, ITEM, MATERIAL, COLOR, "GROUP", GROUP2, SALES, SCORE)
     ON S.CUST_ID = T.CUST_ID
  WHEN MATCHED 
     THEN UPDATE SET SALES = S.SALES, SCORE = S.SCORE
  WHEN NOT MATCHED 
     THEN INSERT VALUES(S.CUST_ID, S.ITEM, S.MATERIAL, S.COLOR, 
                        S."GROUP", S.GROUP2, S.SALES, S.SCORE);
```

Comment: where you did the ```ON s.cust_id = t.cust_id``` I can do 3 or 4 conditions for that ON correct?

Comment: Possibly. I am thinking it processes like any `ON` clause.

Comment: Thank you, trying this now to see if I can get it processed

Comment: It says statement contains wrong number of values. I'm thinking you have to set the update for every column in the values

Comment: So did it work or not? Check your PHP code if you are binding 8 values to prepared statement. I hope in your `ON` you use `AND` between conditions. Also *group* is a [DB2 reserved word](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_reservedwords.html) and should not be used as column name. Try escaping with double quotes.

Comment: It worked just fine after I added the other value from my table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MERGE INTO testSchema.metrics as m
USING (
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALUES 
(:cust_id, :item, :material, :color, :group, :group2, :sales, :score)
) t (cust_id, item, material, color, group, group2, sales, score)
) t on t.cust_id=m.cust_id and t.item=m.item
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET sales = t.sales, score = t.score
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (cust_id, item, material, color, group, group2, sales, score)
VALUES (t.cust_id, t.item, t.material, t.color, t.group, t.group2, t.sales, t.score);
```

Comment: Are you using TABLE as a placeholder in the select? or are you just naming it TABLE since it's selecting those parameters

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question.
I use the way to name the columns in the result set.
`SELECT * FROM TABLE(
VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
) t (cust_id, item, material, color, group, group2, sales, score)`